# How to import user-defined python modules in cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, anaconda, python-module, pythonpath

This might be trivial, but I can't identify the reason for not being able to import user-defined python modules into my python environment. I use Ananconda installation of python in cygwin. I have made entries in bash_profile to append module directory path to PYTHONPATH in this format.

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:"<dirpath>"`

dirpath starts with `/cygdrive/c/Users/`

I have an `__init__.py` file available in the module directory to identify it is a python package.

Kindly provide your inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Python at the startup builds the sys.path using site.py available in the PYTHONHOME directory. I appended to the file, addsitedir(). That worked for me. If there exists a space in the path, use double quotes around the path.